# how to run multiple docker-compose at once

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 4 folders inside a directory. each folder represents a container on its own. each container has its own docker-compose.yaml file. Currently, when I want to run them I have to open up a command prompt and docker-compose up for each of them. Is there a way to run them all at once with a script or something?

```
Project
|-dir1
|  |--docker-compose.yaml
|-dir2
|  |--docker-compose.yaml
|-dir3
|  |--docker-compose.yaml
|-dir4
|  |--docker-compose.yaml
```

Comment: You can use something like this: `for file in $(find . -type f -name docker-compose.yaml); do docker-compose -f $file up; done`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about it:

1. Specify the `-f` flag multiple times, once for each file (e.g. `docker compose -f ./dir1/docker-compose.yaml -f ./dir2/docker-compose.yaml up`). This will merge the configs and run all services in the same network.
2. Use the `-p`, `--project` flag to change the default project when running each (e.g. `docker compose -f ./dir1/docker-compose.yaml -p dir1 up`). This will make it so each will be run in a different network and the runs won't collide with each other.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name